# Hovering a div to change the css on another div

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of a text while the mouse is over another div.

**It will be better explained with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1647/) **:**

What I want to do (with CSS) it that when I move the mouse on the first cicle it changes the color of the text ( Result 1).

I have tried what I found searching previous questions on stackoverflow, by using something like that :

```
div.circleoff:hover ~.test {
    color: #fff
}
```

Comment: this selector: `#schema a.texte` can't be overwritten by `div.circleoff:hover ~.test` which is missing a space after ~ anyway, and i don't see why you need to use the sibilings selector ~, when .texte is INSIDE .circleoff ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a color change of nested elements (not a sibling element), use

```css
#schema>div:hover span { color:white; }
```

This means that hovering over `#schema`'s direct children(`div`ision elements) will cause all its nested `span`s become white.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1651/)

Comment: Thank you Stano, it seems to work well on your jsfiddle. I will test it too.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Meyer has a few demos on his site that will help with exactly this. Look at the 'popup' section. it can easily be adjusted to fit this.

[meyerweb | css/edge](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/)

Comment: Thank you wpenton I will go on meyerweb and learn more about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) of your css selectors. Also, you should not be using the sibling operator. I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1650/) is what you are trying to do (replaced the last 2 rules with the code below).

```
#schema div.circleoff:hover + .circleoff2 .test,
#schema div.circleon:hover + .circleoff2 .texte {
  color: #fff
}
```